# Java HashMap key problems

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

I am currently making a custom serializer as part of a project, and here I need to serialize references too, meaning that if two fields refer to the same project before serializing, they should too after deserializing.

For this, I am using a HashMap, mapping each object to an ID that I can use as an attribute to each object serialized, while at the same time keeping track on which objects that are already serialized. I have stumbled upon some problems though.

It seems that the java HashMap only checks for equality upon keys and not if they are the same reference. For example, in the following, the variable b ends up true:

```
HashMap<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
LinkedList<Object> ll1 = new LinkedList<Object>();
LinkedList<Object> ll2 = new LinkedList<Object>();
map.put(ll1, 5);
boolean b = map.containsKey(ll2);
```

Some times the result does not make sense at all. Here, b is true too:

```
HashMap<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
LinkedList<Object> ll1 = new LinkedList<Object>();
Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<Object>();
map.put(ll1, 5);
boolean b = map.containsKey(stack);
```

What I want is the ContainsKey-method to not only call the equals method, but also use the '=='-operator checking if the reference is the same. Can I do this without needing to look through the whole keyset?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you could do with your own map implementation.

Comment: It doesn't much make sense to use empty LinkedLists as keys to a HashMap, which suggests to me there's something else conceptually wrong with what you're trying to do.  It's unclear exactly what you mean by "I need to serialize references too" but that sets off warning bells to me.  If this is really what you need, Boann's answer ought to work just fine, but I'd encourage you to revisit your serializer's requirements, if you can.

Comment: @dimo414 It makes sense to me. If two references point to the same object, you don't want to serialize it twice, so you need to track which objects have already been processed. Likewise if two objects have references to one another, you need to track them to prevent getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @dimo414 if I refer to a list two places in the program data serialized, I need to be able to change the list from one reference and retrieve the changed list from the second reference. This is not possible if I create a new instance each time I deserialize.

Comment: To me, that's the problem, then.  Attempting to serialize the same list more than once sounds like something that could conceptually be resolved by refactoring the to-be-serialized class, and will likely avoid some confusing behavior down the road.

Comment: Probably, but I am not allowed to change too much on the to-be-serialized classes, so the serializer has to support whatever they contain :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general contract of the Map interface is that two keys are considered equal if they are both null, or if they are not null and `a.equals(b)`. It does not use `==` to compare, unless the key class's implementation of the `equals` method does this.

The reason your `LinkedList` and `Stack` objects are equal is because they both implement the `List` interface, and the definition of [`List.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is that two lists are equal if they have the same size, and contain the same objects in the same order. Since they're both empty, they're "equal".

I believe you're looking for [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html). It deliberately violates the contract of the Map interface to use only `==`, not `Object.equals()` to compare objects. Likewise, for the hash code it uses [`System.identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of any overridden `Object.hashCode()`.